# given $z = e^x\ln(1+y)-y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone help me with the two questions below? I don't exactly understand it. For b) I tried Taylor series.

a) find all critical values if you can by partial s at 2nd degree

b) replace $e^x$ and $\ln(1+y)$ by enough terms to include all quadratic terms

Comment: what does "partial s at 2nd degree" mean? Also, please improve the mathematical notation by using MathJax.

Comment: Pls show us your Taylor series result.